# Can't get my monitor setup to stick with PCLinux OS

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, kde, kde-4, pclinuxos

I'm using PCLinuxOS, which uses the KDE windows manager. I have to reconfigure my dual monitors every time I restart my system. I used the configuration utility to change the enable the second monitor and make it the primary. I always have this problem when I use KDE. Can anyone tell me how to go about fixing this. It's probably something simple that I am overlooking.

Comment: Is there an option to save the configuration after you make it? I know with nvidia's blob drivers you sometimes need to

Comment: I save it, but it doesn't do anything.